# Custom JabRef export (*.layout) similar to Harvard style

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, export, rtf

I tried to create a custom export in JabRef for when I have to cite stuff in word. Here is what the pre-installed Harvard style .rtf looks like (opened in MS Word 2016):

[image: Harvard]

My custom .layout file looks like this so far:

```
\format[AuthorLastFirstAbbreviator, HTMLChars]{\author} (\year). "\format[HTMLChars]{\title}"\format[HTMLChars]{{\journal}} \textbf{\number}(\volume): \pages
```

and the .rtf like this:

[image: custom export]

As you can see, it has a monospace font and ignores formatting completely. Now the strange thing is, even when I directly take the harvard layout file from JabRef and modify that I get monospace font and formatting is ignored.

The format I want/need is as in the custom layout, but the journal title should be underlined and the volume in bold face.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually found the solution with the help of a friend. When you look at the [source of JabRef Hardvard exports](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/tree/master/src/main/resources/resource/layout/harvard) you will see a `harvard.begin.layout` and a `harvard.end.layout` which both need to be in the same directory as the `harvard.layout` (or in my case `harvard.article.layout`).

Alternatively, you can copy `begin` and `end` before and after your modified export file, respectively. My combined solution for now looks like this:

```
{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1251\\uc1\\deff0\\stshfdbch0\\stshfloch0\\stshfhich0\\stshfbi0\\deflang1049\\deflangfe1049{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\froman\\fcharset204\\fprq2{\\*\\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\f39\\froman\\fcharset0\\fprq2 Times New Roman;}
{\\f37\\froman\\fcharset238\\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\\f40\\froman\\fcharset161\\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\\f41\\froman\\fcharset162\\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\\f42\\froman\\fcharset177\\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
{\\f43\\froman\\fcharset178\\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\\f44\\froman\\fcharset186\\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\f45\\froman\\fcharset163\\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}}{

\format[RTFChars,AuthorLastFirstAbbreviator]{\author} (\year), "\format[RTFChars]{\title}". }{\\ul \format[RTFChars]{\journal}\\ul0}{
\begin{volume}
 }{\\b \volume}{
\end{volume}
\begin{number}
(\number)
\end{number}
\begin{pages}
: \pages
\end{pages}.
\\par
\\par

}}
```